# How to notify a fragment that something happened on another fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments

i have 2 fragments on the screen, how can i notify the 2nd that something happened on the 1st ?
now I am using this solution:

```
    companion object {
    private val onFullScreenPressedEvent = SingleLiveEvent<Boolean>()
    val onFullScreenPressed: LiveData<Boolean> = onFullScreenPressedEvent
}
```

and observe onFullScreenPressed from second fragment

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet would be to use a ViewModel tied to the Activity of the Fragments (so shared between fragments), and modify the liveData there.

example Viewmodel

```
class MyActivityViewModel : ViewModel(){

    private val onFullScreenPressedEvent = SingleLiveEvent<Boolean>()
    val onFullScreenPressed: LiveData<Boolean> = onFullScreenPressedEvent

fun onFullScreen(){
    onFullScreenPressedEvent.call()
}}
```

For example, by using `implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.4.0"` you can do in fragment A

```
private val viewModelA: MyActivityViewModel by activityViewModels()
```

and call the code that will change the event `viewModelA.onFullScreen()`

Then in Fragment B

```
private val viewModelB: MyActivityViewModel by activityViewModels()
```

and observe the liveData you trigger in Fragment A `viewModelB.onFullScreenPressed.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, myObserver)`